# Compiling fortran90 modules: .mod vs .o

Tags: makefile, fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I have a main program whose name is main_KMC.f90 and a directory with name modules. In the directory I have the modules that my main program needs. 
Here you have the main_KMC.f90.

```
program main_KMC
use geometry
use search_arguments
use mtfort90
implicit none

integer(8):: d,L,Nitt,warmSteps,measureSteps
integer(8) :: NS,i,nn,itt
integer(8),dimension(:,:),allocatable :: geom
integer(8),dimension(:),allocatable :: S!Vector de spins

T = get_db_arg(1,2.0d0)
d = get_int_arg(2,int(2,8))
L = get_int_arg(3,int(20,8))
Nitt = get_int_arg(4,int(1d6,8))
warmSteps = get_int_arg(5,int(1d3,8))
measureSteps = get_int_arg(6,int(1,8))
....


contains

end program
```

I tried to compile it with a make file:

```
MAIN = main
#MODULES = geometry mtfort search_arguments
MODULES = $(wildcard ./modules/*.f90)
MODULES_OBJ = $(patsubst ./modules/%.f90,%.o,$(MODULES))
MODULES_MOD = $(patsubst ./modules/%.f90,%.mod,$(MODULES))
F90 = gfortran


main.out : $(MODULE_OBJ) $(MAIN).o
    $(F90) -o main.out $(MAIN).o $(MODULE_OBJ)


$(MODULES_OBJ) : $(MODULES)
    $(F90) -c $^

$(MAIN).o: $(MODULE_OBJ) $(MAIN)_KMC.f90
    $(F90) -c $(MAIN)_KMC.f90 -o $(MAIN).o

.PHONY: all
all:
    @echo $(MODULES)
    @echo $(MODULES_OBJ)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @rm *.o
    @rm *.mod

.PHONY: modules
modules:$(MODULES_OBJ)
```

My questions are:
1) Which are the differences between .mod and .out. Because I tried before the make commands

```
$(MODULES_OBJ) : $(MODULES)
    $(F90) -c $^ -o $(MODULES_OBJ)
```

And when I execut the Makefile, appear the following error:

```
use geometry 
     1 
 Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'geometry.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
 make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I thought that with the object files, you had enought to compile the program.

The second problem that I have is with the first Makefile. When I run it it appears the following errors:

```
compilando main.out
gfortran -o main.out main.o 
main.o: In function `MAIN__':
main_KMC.f90:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `__search_arguments_MOD_get_db_arg'
main_KMC.f90:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `__search_arguments_MOD_get_int_arg'
main_KMC.f90:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to `__search_arguments_MOD_get_int_arg'
main_KMC.f90:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `__search_arguments_MOD_get_int_arg'
main_KMC.f90:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `__search_arguments_MOD_get_int_arg'
main_KMC.f90:(.text+0xa6): undefined reference to `__search_arguments_MOD_get_int_arg'
main_KMC.f90:(.text+0x48a): undefined reference to `__geometry_MOD_geometry_compute'
main_KMC.f90:(.text+0x55b): undefined reference to `__mtfort90_MOD_grnd'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main.out] Error 1
```

Comment: mod is just a quick lookup table for modules.  They get generated whenever a module is built.  You need to work out the hierarchy of what calls what and rearrange the build order accordingly.  You will probably need to do it in two passes if it is recursive.

Comment: "I thought that with the object files, you had enought to compile the program."  Not with Fortran90.  The compiler must be able to find both the *.o and *.mod files.

Comment: No, the compiler doesn't need to find the .o files, but the linker does.